# In mule 4, is there a way to grab the payload in html page using Load static resources connector to display the html with the payload?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I'm unable to display an array of strings from payload to the html page being loaded using the Load static resources connector. Is this possible or is there a better way of displaying the payload? I'm attempting to put the payload within a form tag with each string in the array being a checkbox.

```
<flow name="Flow">
    <http:listener doc:name="Listener" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/*"/>
    <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" >
        <ee:message >
        </ee:message>
        <ee:variables >
            <ee:set-variable variableName="attributes" >
<![CDATA[%dw 2.0 output application/java ---
attributes]]></ee:set-variable>
        </ee:variables>
    </ee:transform>
    <flow-ref doc:name="Flow Reference" name="Flow1"/>
    <http:load-static-resource doc:name="Load static resource" resourceBasePath="src\main\resources\web\" attributes="#[vars.attributes]"/>
</flow>
```

HTML

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>data retrieval</h1>

<form action="#" method="POST">
    Objects:
    //loop each string in array 
    <input type="checkbox" name="objects" >
        <script>eval('(' + payload +')');</script>
    </input>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add the flow and the HTML template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load static resource operation, as its name says, it for static resources that do not change dynamically, ie with data.

The [Parse Template](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/parse-template-reference) operation seems to be what you are looking for. You can use DataWeave expressions inside the file.

Example:

Flow:

```
<parse-template location="form.html" doc:name="Parse Template"/>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
         <tr>
            <td>#[payload['name']]</td>
            <td>#[payload['address']]</td>
         </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does parse-template allow javascript either by script tag or js file?

Comment: parse-template doesn't know about the contents of the file. It will only replace the expression marker by the results of evaluating them. Other than that it can be anything.